# Any wordpress form building plugin for my requirements?

Tags: forms, validation, plugins, wordpress

I'm looking for a WP plugin which can allow me to create different forms and embed them on pages and following are the requirements:

1. Only a single textbox required in each of those forms
2. The submit button will only be shown if a custom entry/answer is inputted into the textbox. (basically a client-side validation)
3. The submitted answer should be stored in the back-end with the usermeta (or just the username of the user logged in) so that I can export the entries in a format like csv, etc.

Any thoughts?

P.S. I have found one but not sure if the PRO version of this allows me to have a validation for a custom text. This is the plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/visual-form-builder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity Forms is the most robust form builder plugin for WordPress.  You can, with the right knowledge and skills, make it do pretty much anything you'd like.  You can find it here: [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/).

Comment: That plugin is just awesome. Thanks very much for that mate. :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.  Gravity Forms is simply amazing, it's really only limited by your imagination!

Answer (score 0):

Very well, I've found this. There are actually good plugins however, you will have to purchase it. I'm looking for a free one. http://www.webdesignboom.com/2013/formcraft-wordpress-form-builder/